# How to assign middle mouse click to two finger tap?

Tags: 12.04, mouse, trackpad

I have just updated to 12.04 and I am trying to assign two finger tap to my track pad. I know the code, just need to understand how to set it permanently because at the moment I need to input the code into the terminal every time I log on.

Here is the code and it works.

```
xinput set-int-prop 13 291 8 2 3 0 0 1 2 3
```

But how do I set this permanently?

Answer (score 1):

### You can create a script and add it to your startup applications

---

1. Create a new document (say **mouseMod**) somewhere (say in your `Documents` folder)
2. Add the following lines to it:

   > #!/bin/bash
   >      xinput set-int-prop 13 291 8 2 3 0 0 1 2 3
3. Make it executable by opening a terminal and typing/running the following     command:

   > chmod +x ~/Documents/mouseMod
4. Finally, add the file to your startup applications (I'm not sure where it is in `12.04`, but in `11.10` I found it by searching for startup in the dash) by clicking add and browsing to/selecting the script (i.e. **mouseMod**).